# Jquery submit not triggering controller action method correctly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When the form is submitted the uploadimage action is called but there is a id in fron of it, maybe my route config isn't right?

it's submitting managespace/4/uploadimage
the html rendered looks like this

```
<form action="/ManageSpaces/4/UploadImage"
```

route config

```
routes.MapRoute("ManageSpaces",
            "ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "ManageSpaces"}, //removed action = "overview" from default - this would make it optional, now its mandatory 
            new { id = @"\d+" } //The regular expression \d+ matches one or more integers
            );
```

jquery

```
$('#selectedFile').change(function() {
    $('#imageajaxForm').submit();
});
```

```html
<div id="images">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadImage", "ManageSpaces", new { id = Model.SpaceId }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "get",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "imageList"
            }, new { id = "imageajaxForm" }))
            {
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TeacherImageFileBase, new { @type = "file", id = "selectedFile", style = "display: none;" })*@
                <input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
                <input type="button" value="Add Photos" class="btn" id="pictureupload" />
            }
            <div id="imageList">
                @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
                {
                    <h4>this is an image</h4>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

action method in controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(int id)
    {
        return Json("Saved");
    }
```

Comment: You dont have a control with `id="imageajaxForm"`

Comment: what about new { name = "imageajaxForm" } I tried it with id but it still didn't work

Comment: Check the html your generating. `new { id = "imageajaxForm" }` (the last parameter of `Ajax.BeginForm()`) should result in `<form .... id="imageajaxForm" ...>`

Comment: Now you have completely changed the question! You specify the `id` route parameter using `new { id = Model.SpaceId }` and the route is defined as `ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}` which results in `action="/ManageSpaces/4/UploadImage"` (assuming the value of `SpaceId = 4`). How do you want the url to look?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there is something worong with the way I've named my form

Yes, right now you have `new { name = "imageajaxForm" }` but in your javascript code you use `$('#imageajaxForm')` which means that you should give your form an `id`, not a `name`:

```
new { id = "imageajaxForm" }
```

Comment: I changed the the name to id and it is trying to submit to /ManageSpaces/4/UploadImage. This includes an id in the url, which I don't want. How do I prevent this?

Comment: The url is generated by your `Ajax.BeginForm`. There you have included the id: `new { id = Model.SpaceId }`. And since you have a route defined as `ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}` it will generate BeginForm method will respect this pattern. Obviously you can remove it but then your controller action will no longer work as it currently expects an id integer parameter. So it is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.